# Why `container-type: size` CSS prop sets height to zero?

Tags: css, css-contain

And how to bring height back, keeping `container-type: size` in place?
Sample: https://jsfiddle.net/yakunins/cy3b68uk/

```
<div style="container-type: size;">Height of this div is zero.</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it sets size containment. A size container cannot depend on the size of its contents, so it behaves as if its content size is 0.

You must set an explicit height for the size container.

Comment: Thank you! Is this behavior have specs somewhere?

Comment: @yakunins [container type: size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain-3/#valdef-container-type-size); [containment size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain-2/#containment-size); and [sizing-as-if-empty](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-contain-2/#sizing-as-if-empty)

Comment: Sadly, this makes container-type: size quite useless.

Answer (score 0):

Container type [doesn't have full support](https://caniuse.com/?search=container-type) yet, as of 18th Nov 22.

Elements that use container size must have a defined size property, as the child elements will use a portion of this to calculate their own sizes.

Comment: There are no elements that use container size in a sample. `document.querySelector('body > div.c2').offsetHeight = 0` 
Chrome is up to date Version 107.0.5304.110 (Official Build) (arm64)